# assigning dataframe filter result to variable

Tags: python, pandas, filter

I am trying to make calculations based on the cell values after a filter is applied. I have never encountered this problem before and suddenly it seems an issue and I do not know that I have to do.

```
transacties_klant DataFrame:

    crm_ref year quarter LitersSold
3   V000095 20  1.0 60.00
4   V000095 20  3.0 180.00
5   V000095 21  2.0 360.00
6   V000095 21  3.0 11.20
7   V000095 21  4.0 649.04
8   V000095 22  1.0 1107.00
9   V000095 22  2.0 3100.80
10  V000095 22  3.0 2164.20
```

The output of this code should be the variable containing an float but instead it returns a? Series, dataframe, multi-index?

```
last_quarter_year = 22
last_quarter = 2
last_quarter_sum = transacties_klant[(transacties_klant['year']==last_quarter_year) & (transacties_klant['quarter']==last_quarter)]['LitersSold']
quarter_before_sum = transacties_klant[(transacties_klant['year']==(last_quarter_year-1)) & (transacties_klant['quarter']==last_quarter)]['LitersSold']
print(last_quarter_sum)
```

However the current output is like this:

```
9    3100.8
Name: LitersSold, dtype: float64
```

I have already tried the .astype() and .values().
What do I need to change so **last_quarter_sum** = 3100.8 ?

Comment: Only one row matched the selection criteria. What if several had matched? Would you want a sum of all of them? Can more than one row match?

Comment: In this case it can not, because I already used a groupby.sum() to sum it up. But I might use your tip of using sum to keep more information and sum in the method. Thanks!

Comment: I was mostly interested in how to handle the series. If you expect 1 result from the filter, then you'd index with `[0]` (and deal with selecting an empty series).

Answer (score 0):

you need to extract the value from the result set

```
last_quarter_sum.values[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`squeeze`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.squeeze.html):

```
last_quarter_sum = (transacties_klant
                   .loc[(transacties_klant['year']==last_quarter_year)
                      & (transacties_klant['quarter']==last_quarter),
                       'LitersSold'].squeeze()
                    )
```

Answer (score 0):

`transacties_klant[(transacties_klant['year']==last_quarter_year) & (transacties_klant['quarter']==last_quarter)]` created a dataframe holding only the rows you selected. Adding `['LitersSold']` after that selects a single column of the dataframe expressed as as `Series` object. That `Series` could have zero or more entries. If you want the sum of all matching rows, use `.sum()` to complete.

```
last_quarter_sum = transacties_klant[(transacties_klant['year']==last_quarter_year) & (transacties_klant['quarter']==last_quarter)]['LitersSold'].sum()
```